# Admob 6.1.0 for monodroid

Tags: android, xamarin.android, admob

I have an app made with monodroid, it's on release stage (ready to get released) but I would like to have a free ad-supported version of my app. I've been searching the web for a tutorial of Admob 6.1.0 implementation on monodroid without any luck. I'd have to mention that I've never worked with ads before.

I was wondering if anyone has been able to use Admob 6.1.0 on monodroid and if you could share your knowledge

I've seen [this](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MonoDroid-Admob6/tree/master/AdMob6Sample) source code and also [this](http://www.gregshackles.com/2011/02/using-admob-in-a-monodroid-application/) tutorial, but I just can't manage to understand correctly how to implement it. I't  would be nice if someone could make an answer as a community wiki so it can help others to get introduced to Admob in monodroid

EDIT:

Tried Greg Shackles sample step by step, i'm now getting this error `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView`. Any sugestion of how to make it work?

EDIT 2:

Changed the XML file and now getting 2 new errors: `Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError` and `System.TypeInitializationException`. XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/Background2"
    >
  <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
                           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           ads:adSize="BANNER"
                           ads:adUnitId="AD_UNIT_ID_GOES_HERE"
                           ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR,TEST_DEVICE_ID_GOES_HERE"
                           ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And adview is called like this:

```
public class MyActivity : Activity
    {
        private View _adView;
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.AboutActivityLayout);
            AdMobHelper.RegisterEmulatorAsTestDevice();
            _adView = FindViewById(Resource.Id.Ad);
            AdMobHelper.RequestFreshAd(_adView);

            loadData();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The first error you got "android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView" is related to the Jar Build Action setting.

You should check two things first:

1. the jar file has the Build Action property set to "AndroidJavaLibrary"
2. the java file called "AdMobHelper.java" should have the Build Action property set to "AndroidJavaSource"

It seems to me that the error you are getting now is related to the java file not being correctly configured as an AndroidJavaSource.